# Description of Edward Lessingham descended from Emperor Fredrick II by E.R. Eddison

Tags: worm-ouroboros, zimiamvia

I hope that someone can provide a quote from E.R. Eddison describing his character Edward Lessingham.

I think I remember reading a description of the achievements of Edward Lessingham in his life on Earth at the beginning of either *The Worm Ouroboros* or *Mistress of Mistresses*.

According to that description, Lessingham's achievements included writing a biography of his great ancestor Emperor Frederick II (1194-1250).

Somewhere I read a commentary claiming that description of Lesshingham's life was the kind of life that Eddison would have wanted to have lived.

And I would appreciate it if someone could quote that passage mentioning that Lessingham was descended from Emperor Frederick II.

Comment: It's from the latter book you mention "I knew he traced his descent through many generations of English forefathers to King Eric Bloodaxe in York, the son of Harald Hairfair, that Charlemagne of the north, and, by the female line, from the greatest ruler of men that appeared in Europe in the thousand years between Charlemagne and Napoleon: the Emperor Frederick II.... In after years I helped Lessingham a good deal in collecting material for his ten-volume History of Frederick II"